# Apache server in local computer needs to be run on internet

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, ip-address

I have gone read your answer for "What is port forwarding and what is it used for?" question.Your explanation is great.I have one doubt please clarify that.
I'm running a apache server application in my local computer,All of computers connected to my router is able to access but a computer outside from router not able to access my application.as you said i have configured port forwarding also like ipaddress:192.168.0.100 and external & internal port:80.
please tell me how to access my application from anywhere.